# The result returned from ip conflict with the one retrieved from google

Tags: ip

I am running on MacOS Majave

When issue command `ip`, it returns

```
$ ip
211.137.170.246
```

However, google returns an answer:

[image]

Which one should I trust?

Comment: Are you in tianjin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends what you mean by "trust".  Google will tell you the "from" address on your request.  `ip` will tell you the address your laptop has.  They may both be correct.

It is common with IPv4 to give a local IP to laptops, phones (anything that's not a server) and replace this through a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) gateway (your home router?). That way all machines on your local network share the same external IP, but each have their own local IP.

So what you are seeing is that somewhere between you and google your connection is going through a NAT gateway.  To the outside world you have 47.91.28.150.  On your local network you have 211.137.170.246.

Note that some ISPs now use [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). So even if you think you're not connected to the internet via a NAT router, your ISP might still be sending traffic through a NAT.

Comment: It may also be a web proxy.

Comment: Yup the effect of that might be as transparent as NAT.  Except it may mean traffic to port 80 and 443 show up with a different external IP to traffic bound for other ports.